# How to show where's the match occured in a column in game?

Tags: android

I am making a game demo in which i there are 3 rows and in each row there are 9 images and we have to match the images vertically. If there is a match than the hit will occur and on that place the new images will come. I did this much of work.
But the problem is I want when there is a hit the column in which the hit occured must invisible for 500ms so that the user come to know in which column the hit occured or any other indication to the user. Can anyone tell please what must i do regarding this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            Drawable d1 = iv1[i].getDrawable();
            Drawable d2 = iv2[i].getDrawable();
            Drawable d3 = iv3[i].getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d1).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) d2).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap3 = ((BitmapDrawable) d3).getBitmap();

            if (bitmap == bitmap2 && bitmap2 == bitmap3) {


                score = score + 100;
                iv1[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                iv2[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                iv3[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                hit = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hit);
                hit.start();
                hit.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        hit.release();

                    }
                });


                tv2.setText("" + score);
                Random raj = new Random();
                int ww = raj.nextInt(4);
                int xx = raj.nextInt(4);
                int zz = raj.nextInt(4);

                while (ww == xx && xx == zz) {
                    ww = raj.nextInt(4);

                }
                iv1[i].setImageResource((k[ww]));
                iv2[i].setImageResource((k[xx]));
                iv3[i].setImageResource((k[zz]));
                iv1[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv2[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv3[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

update 1:

I used this

```
if (bitmap == bitmap2 && bitmap2 == bitmap3) {


                score = score + 100;

                iv1[1].setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anim1);
                AnimationDrawable loadingViewAnim = (AnimationDrawable) iv1[i].getBackground();
                loadingViewAnim.start();
```

an d i created anim folder in res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kejriwal"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/modi"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rahul"
        android:duration="150"/>
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know the imageView that are included in the match from your loop. iv1[i],iv2[i],iv3[i]. Now you can set Some Animation to these views using AnimationDrawable. AnimationDrawable is a PPT type animations that you define in a XML by defining the duaration, transition etc. 
Following is an example:

```
iv[1].setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loading_animation);
AnimationDrawable loadingViewAnim = (AnimationDrawable) iv[1].getBackground();
loadingViewAnim.start();
```

**R.anim.loading_animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/loader_1"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/loader_2"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/loader_3"
        android:duration="150"/>
</animation-list>
```

Then finally you need to detect the termination of this animation and continue your game's flow.

Comment: no hit is a sound that is played on a match occured

Comment: i want to give the indication to user that in which row the match occured

Comment: thanks for your answer do i have to add a new xml file

Comment: @Abhi yes try adding a new xml file to a folder res/anim.
Here @drawable/loader_1 etc are images in Drawable folder, just replace them with any test images to see what result this fetches you

Comment: its giving exception in this line loadingViewAnim.start();

Comment: What is the exception? Do this stuff on a UI thread and also you need have the drawable files that you have listed in your Animation XML.